# Underscores and dashes not visible

Tags: html, css

I am working with SocialEngine4 application of Zend and have my css like this:

```
#1_1_17-element {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  height: 215px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

but it is not affecting expected element on page.

[Here's an example of the selector not working](http://jsfiddle.net/GokulSolace/F2jGs/2/).

Comment: Where’s the HTML? Can you setup a working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Here is JSFiddle  link http://jsfiddle.net/GokulSolace/F2jGs/2/

Comment: Votes to close are completely inappropriate. The user is demonstrating a selector which cannot work. This is a clear problem with tangible solutions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**[UPDATED]** Underscores in ID names are not recommended and not supported in CSS2:

> ..."CSS2, published in 1998, also forbade the use of underscores in class and ID names."

See reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Underscores_in_class_and_ID_Names

I recommend you to rename it, maybe something more similar to this ( without _ ):

```
#global-page-user-signup-fields form #a1-1-17-element {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
  height: 215px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: The class name isn't a problem in practice. The problem is with the ID starting with a character other than `[A-Za-z]`. [Replacing the underscores with hyphens in the OP's code doesn't solve the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/LBfDp/), [but placing a letter as the first character (without removing underscores) does work](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/n7jc3/).

Answer (score 1):

urbz has an interesting answer. Regardless of whether they are technically permitted or not, underscores and hyphens are commonly used in CSS classes and in living memory I have never had a problem with this. For instance, the reasonably popular [BEM pattern](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/) mandates use of underscores and hyphens to describe semantic structures in CSS classes.

IDs are more restrictive. As [Mathias Bynens elucidates in this excellent article](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class), the HTML specification up to 4.01 mandates that IDs *must* start with a letter (not a number, as you are currently using) – and I've had this problem in the past. HTML5 has removed this arbitrary restriction.

[As you can see in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/n7jc3/), prepending a letter to the ID (in the HTML and the CSS) makes the styles work:

```
#1_1_17-element { /* won't work */ }
#e1_1_17-element { /* will work */ }
```

Comment: I agree with you, but I think that the pattern of not naming ID nor class names with underscores should follow consistently to make you hopefully get away from occuring problems as stated above.